# Error in db with modeltranslation in django

Tags: python, django, django-modeltranslation

I want to add internationalization to a project, so I use django-modeltranslation app. However, after following all the steps of configuration and running migrations, when I enter in my admin the model is registered, but when I click on it:

"Something's wrong with your database installation. Make sure the appropriate database tables have been created, and make sure the database is readable by the appropriate user."

Here's the code (note I have put it all in a file for clarity):

```html
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'modeltranslation',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'nuggets',
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'Trans',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'c1l2a3u4',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('es', gettext('Spanish')),
)
```

```html
#Models code
from django.db import models
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()


#Admin code
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import News
from modeltranslation.admin import TranslationAdmin

class NewsAdmin(TranslationAdmin):
 pass

admin.site.register(News, NewsAdmin)


#translation.py code
from modeltranslation.translator import translator, TranslationOptions
from .models import News

class NewsTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('title', 'text',)

translator.register(News, NewsTranslationOptions)
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FgP6.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FgP6.png)

I have tried before createing the models, after, with default db, with postgre... Nothing seems to work, help please!

Comment: You say 'after running migrations' but did you try to `makemigration` to see if it generates the new translations fields for your model (and then running them!)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like django-modeltranslation doesn't workwith django 2.0 (at least for me and the installation procedure out there). But it does with django 1.11.

Answer (score 8):

I had the similar problem with django-modeltranslation.
In Django 2.0.5 I had an error when I opened the admin panel.

Need to update package:

> pip install django-modeltranslation==0.13-beta1

update the translations:

> python manage.py update_translation_fields

And everything works fine.

Comment: Yeap! That did the trick. I have mistakenly did `pipenv update` which installed `modeltranslation==12` where `==0.13b1` should be used instead. Thanks Igor!

Answer (score 1):

OP is using `django-modeltranslation` with `Django` 2.0. But their tests are [currently failing](https://travis-ci.org/deschler/django-modeltranslation/jobs/335590961) for this version.

---

Use `ugettext_lazy` in your `settings.py` to avoid circular imports:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en', _('English')),
    ('th', _('Thai')),
]

MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'en'
MODELTRANSLATION_LANGUAGES = ('en', 'th')
```

Try to put your `modeltranslation` at the end of your `INSTALLED_APPS`, after the `django` defaults.

Have you registered your model somewhere else? You can try to unregister it before you register it again.

```
admin.site.unregister(News)
admin.site.register(News, NewsAdmin)
```

Are you following the steps with [`python manage.py makemigration`](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/registration.html?highlight=makemigration#migrations-django-1-7), as stated in the docs?

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried both ugettext and lazy. Putting modeltranslation at the end doesn't work, since as the docs explain: "If you want to use the admin integration, modeltranslation must be put before django.contrib.admin". It still doesn't work, I don't know what else to try... Have you ever used it? Cause it may have bugs or sth...

Comment: Yes, I am successfully using TranslationAdmin with ``django`` 1.11.5 and ``django-modeltranslation`` 0.12.1. Have you set your ``SITE_ID``?

Comment: The only difference that I can see is that I put ``django.contrib.admin`` at the very end of my ``INSTALLED_APPS `` like so: https://pastebin.com/raw/CdnAdNmy

Comment: At last. I was doing it with django 2.0, and once I switched to 1.11 it immediately worked. Do you think it is not supported? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Their tests are failing with ``django`` 2.0. https://travis-ci.org/deschler/django-modeltranslation.

Comment: Sorry for the bump but would be nice if you can accept an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems "modeltranslations" is no longer being maintained at that particular library name. And later versions of django require on_delete to be set for models.ForeignKey

For me this worked:

```
pip uninstall modeltranslations
pip install django-modeltranslations
```

As far as I can tell it's the same library, but you get a newer version. In my case, I did not need to modify settings.py at all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [the `sync_translation_fields` Management Command](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html#the-sync-translation-fields-command)?

> This command compares the database and translated models definitions (finding new translation fields) and provides SQL statements to alter tables. You should run this command after adding a new language to your `settings.LANGUAGES` or a new field to the `TranslationOptions` of a registered model.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried it but and it returned "No new changes". It still doesn't work, and I don't really know what else to try, I have been days with it...

Answer (score 0):

My configuration: Django 2.2.5, Python 3.7.4, bootstrap4-0.1.0

edit ~/anaconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modeltranslation/models.py, add **on_delete=models.CASCADE**

```
creator_user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, default=None, related_name='model_translation', verbose_name=u"User translator", help_text=u"User that created last translation version", on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
```

edit /anaconda3/envs/django/lib/python3.7/site-packages/modeltranslation/migrations/0001_initial.py, add 
**import django.db.models.deletion**
and **on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE,**

```
from django.db import models, migrations
import django.db.models.deletion

('creator_user', models.ForeignKey(related_name='model_translation', default=None, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, help_text='Usuario que ha realizado la \xfaltima traducci\xf3n', null=True, verbose_name='Usuario que ha realizado la traducci\xf3n')),

In settings.py
# ModelTranslation
IS_MONOLINGUAL=False
TRANSLATABLE_MODEL_MODULES = ["marketplace.models"]
```

Modify this with your apps name, 
TRANSLATABLE_MODEL_MODULES = [".models"]

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Hope it works for your case too.

Comment: This works, however, hardly a good solution to patch downloaded packages. For me, the problem came back right after trying to deploy to heroku.